# Image not displaying as background of button when using a valueconverter

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to set the background of an image using a ValueConverter, when I set the background Image directly in the XAML it does display but when using the converter it doesn't display.

My XAML code for creating the button:

```
<Button x:Name="image" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 0, -1, 0" Width="100" Height="100" Click="image_CLick">
   <Button.Background>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=isSaved, Converter={StaticResource BoolImageConverter}}"/>
   </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

The isSaved property is the boolean used to determine what image to show.

Here is my ValueConverter code, I've tried using an Uri as return type but also already tried a BitmapImage or String. But ImageSource (according to MSDN) is an Uri.

```
public class BoolToImage : IValueConverter
{
    public Uri TrueImage = new Uri("/Images/ThumbSelected@2x.png", UriKind.Relative);
    public Uri FalseImage = new Uri("/Images/thumb.png", UriKind.Relative);

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo   culture)
    {
        if (!(value is bool))
        {
            return this.FalseImage;
        }

        bool b = (bool)value;
        if (b)
        {
            return this.TrueImage;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.FalseImage;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This ValueConverter works for a normal Image element if I change the return types to a BitmapImage.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I assume you have tried the obvious like removing the leading "/" from your Uri path and changing the "/" to "\"?

Comment: @TylerD87 Visual Studio states that '\' is an unrecognized escape sequence.

Comment: change the path to @"Images\ThumbSelected@2x.png". The @ sign before tells the compiler to ignore escape characters. Alternatively you can write it as "Images\\ThumbSelected@2x.png"

Comment: @TylerD87 Awesome that worked! You could put it in as an answer, so I can accept it. It is the valid answer.

Comment: Cheers I've done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the paths to:

```
@"Images\ThumbSelected@2x.png"
```

and

```
@"Images\thumb.png"
```

?